# Inheritance and Composition problem in class Diagram

Tags: inheritance, uml, software-design, composition, class-diagram

So there is a small scenario from a big system. It is a Car Booking System where User class needs to be more cohesive. In my Initial Scenario, My **User** class was catering User operations, User Verification, User Profile and had a different class for **Admin**.

1. team was instructed to make **User** class more *cohesive*
2. Break **User** into **UserProfile** and make the **Verification Process** separate from this class
3. As **Admin** is also a **User** so you can inherit **Admin** from **User**.

[image: Inheritance performed]

4. **Admin** will inherit the **UserProfile** part but the **Verification Process** will only be applicable to customer.

now this is where I got stuck and I don't know how the User Verification can only connect to **User** which is parent class but not goes to the child class. as **Admin** don't need any verification process.

My suggested solution is:

[image]
but I am very unsure about inheriting two users and specially when the **Customer** class have all methods of Verification, that means Class name dont represent it's actual functionality.

Comment: Part of the problem is that your `User` class is trying to serve both as a data object representing a user and as a functional object providing services related to users.  This is what puts you in the situation that the services provided by that class are not applicable to all instances of the class.  Generally speaking, it's a good idea to maintain a separation between classes that represent entities from the system's domain and classes that implement your system's behaviors.

Comment: Your `UserProfile` is close to a domain entity.  Your `User`, `Admin`, and `UserVerification` all seem mainly to be trying to provide system behavior.  Thus, a better design, IMO, would not involve any inheritance or composition relationships among any of these.  But `UserProfile` might be *used* by the other three.

Comment: you are right that **Admin** and **User** provide system behavior, but we cant deny the nature of their behaviors thus, **Admin** inherited from **User** providing same behavior of log_in( ), log_out( ) makes sense.

Comment: What about the nature of the behaviors leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: Makes no sense that `User` provides `login()`. That's clearly a part for some authorization system (which would deal with a user object). I'd say your design is just broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How is the design?

Your suggested solution is an interesting start. It separates:

- the `User`, which exposes operations that could be driven by some user interface,
- the `UserProfile`, which manages the personal information of a user,
- the user's role, i.e. `Customer` role or `Admin`, which provides role specific behaviors and responsibilities.

The main weakness of this design is an insufficient separation of concerns.

#### Separating user-interface behavior from internal behavior

Some of your classes seem to be domain classes but seem at the same time to be supposed to have user-interface responsibilities (e.g. `UserProfile` and `editProfile()` )

If this is a toy project with a command line interface, it's ok. But a safer approach would be to focus on classes that could be invoked by a user interface with some data, but without having itself any user-interface responsibility (e.g. `editProfile()`  would be replaced with getters that would allow a form to populate content,  and setters, to update the class once the form is validated).

#### Separate responsibilities using the decorator pattern

`Customer` and `Admin` both add different sets of responsibilities and attributes to the user.  Instead of using inheritance,  you could prefer composition and use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern): `Customer` and `Admin` would then be decorators of `User`,  where `Customer` would add the responsibility to manage the verification.

A slight improvement would be to make the distinction between a `User` and a `UserRole`.  A  `UserRole` would be an abstract class,  and Customer and Admin would be decorators of the role.

This would allow you to easily introduce new roles (`Supplier`, `Auditor`, ...) without changing the design of the users.   You could even allow multiple roles at the same time if you change multiplicity on the `UserRole` side of the composition.

#### Implement policies with the strategy pattern

Another problem that you have introduced in your solution is that the `UserVerification` was merged part into `UserProfile` and part into `Customer`.  This is not a sound separation of concerns.

A better approach is to make `UserVerification` a [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) of a `UserRole`.  You could decide to set the strategy in the construction of each specific `UserRole`.  The `Admin` could then use a light strategy that considers a user as always verified without further steps.

#### Some more (unrelated) thoughts

Never ever store passwords.  The interaction should not be:  "ask password, then get profile password and verify if they are the same", but "ask password, compute a password hash code,  check if the hash code matches".

In this regard, you may consider extracting password related properties and operations into a separate class.  This would allow to change user authentication strategies exists and opt of OS authentication, 2FA authentication, single sign on, and other authentication approaches.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explained answer. It really helped me a lot and cleared the whole concept, not just this but I got a chance to learn new patterns that I was lacking behind. Thank you.

Comment: @SyedBilalHaiderBukhari Thank you very much for this positive feedback.  I am glad that it helped :-)